# I have installed ubuntu 12.04 on a pc and I'm sharing the desktop to a win machine but the screen is not refreshing

Tags: remote-desktop

The image is always the same as the first image. It never updates the screen.

How may I fix it? thanks

Comment: What software are you using to share the screen? VNC? What Windows client are you using?

Comment: the default app that comes with win vista or win 7

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When login click on the gear and select "Ubuntu 2D" or "Gnome classic (without effects)". The "Ubuntu 2D" works better than the "Gnome classic (without effects)" at refreshing the screen...

Hope I discovered this earlier.